# Bootstrap Rows side-by-side when resizing

Tags: rows

Can you help me with the following:
I wish for this 2 rows to stand side-by-side when minimizing the screen.
I can't create a div inside the div's with an ID because they will be overridden with data from a JavaScript function.

```
<div class="row">         
    <div class="col-md-3" id="dias">360</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="horas">24</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="minutos">60</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="segundos">60</div>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-3">Dias</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Horas</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Minutos</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Segundos</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use nested grids. Put them both inside a div and change their class attribute from `class="row"` to `class="col-xs-2"` or `class="col-sm-2"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up nesting it like this and it works just like I wanted.

```
<div class="row">    

      **<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">** 

            <div class="col-md-3" id="dias">360</div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="horas">24</div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="minutos">60</div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="segundos">60</div>

        </div>

      **<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">**  

            <div class="col-md-3">Dias</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Horas</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Minutos</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Segundos</div>

        </div>

        </div>
```